# Monochrome colouring effect

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to implement gray scale level of monochrome image in iphone. if any know the links to the tutorials then plz mention them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out following llink may help you

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-SW4

Comment: Please note that the above link is for OSX development - for iOS is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101